# Anyone tried this? SFMC v2 and v5 Connector in the same SFDC instance

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Has anyone setup SFDC Performance Edition with both the v2 package and v5 package (Marketing Cloud Connect)? The two packages would point to separate SFMC accounts -- we're in the middle of migrating from a SFMC Advanced account to an E2.0 account and need to have both accounts running in parallel for a short period of time.

Comment: If both of them can be installed at the same time, then there shouldn't be any issue, but if they can't, then not. Maybe set up a sandbox and try it out?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @sfdcfox for taking a look and suggesting the sandbox. This past week we were able to successfully connect two SFMC instances to one SFDC instance.

Our set up looks like this:

SFMC Advanced account connected using v2 connector with a SFMC api user (SFMC_api_user_1) and corresponding SFDC api user (SFDC_api_user_1).

SFMC E2.0 account connected using v5 / Marketing Cloud Connect with a SFMC api user (SFMC_api_user_2) and corresponding SFDC api user (SFDC_api_user_2).

Both SFMC accounts are connected to the same SFDC production account.

It seems the key is using different connector versions as the connection itself is implemented differently and also using api users in both SFMC and SFDC that are specific to the connector and SFMC account.

Otherwise when we did the new v5 connection it was as simple as following the online documentation.

Hopefully, this helps someone else who's considered trying this.